# Ctrl+a to select all in listview powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on the listview which by default it is not an option. Using `keypress` events to replicate this behaviour is not working.

`Keypress` works for single key down event but when I use it with combination of keys it does not work.
For testing I have attempted the following:

```
$droper.Add_keypress({if ($_.KeyCode -Eq 17) {
                                           write-host "ctrl a pressed"}})
```

the above one is successfull

```
$droper.Add_keypress({if ($_.KeyCode -Eq (17 -and 65) ) {
                                           write-host "ctrl a pressed"}})
```

this does not work

```
$droper.Add_keypress({if (($_.KeyCode -Eq 17) -and ($_.KeyCode -Eq 65) ) {
                                           write-host "ctrl a pressed"}})
```

This as well does not work
Any help on this is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the params from the event, particularly `$e` which is of type KeyEventArgs:

```
$droper.Add_keypress({
    param($sender, $e)
    if ($e.control) { write-host "ctrl a pressed"}
    })
```

Note that `$e` has member variables for Alt, Control and Shift (among others) which are booleans.

Then you can do this to check if CTRL + A is pressed:

```
if($_.KeyCode -eq "A" -and $e.Control)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked with Key_down event with the above method